# Merge masked selection of array with original array

Tags: numpy

I'm facing a problem with an assignment at the moment.

So I have an array which contains 400 2d Points. So an array of shape 400 X 2.
Then I have a mask that selects m points (rows) that I wanna compute some changes on.
As per the assignment I'm supposed to store the points that I want to change in an array of shape m X 2.

Then I do my changes on this resulting array. But now after the changes I want to insert these new computed values in my original array at the original indices. And I just have no clue how to do that.

So I basically have:

- orig (400 X 2)
- mask (400 X 1) (boolean mask selecting the rows to edit)
- change (m X 2) (just the changes I want to add)
- changed (m X 2) (the original values + the change (with a factor applied) added together

How do I transform my change or changed arrays with the mask so that I can add/insert the changes into my original array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example with 4 rows.
The principle is that the mask that "extract" from orig can also return the sub-array to the original place.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
print(x)

mask_ix = np.array([True,False, True, False])
masked = x[mask_ix,:]
masked = masked * 10 # the change

print(masked)
x[mask_ix] = masked  # return to the original x in the mask_ix mask
print(x)

 x =[[1 2]
     [3 4]
     [5 6]
     [7 8]]

masked = [[10 20]
          [50 60]]

x = [[10 20]
     [ 3  4]
     [50 60]
     [ 7  8]]
```